# It looks like I'm instantiating this SpeechAPI interface. How is that possible?

Tags: class, interface, instance

I am using Microsoft Text-to-Text Speech feature in my project. But I have a question about that, actually not directly about that. So :

Normally programmers when creating Interface, they put I as a prefix of the interface name like IReadable,IEnumerator etc. But I've come across something that actually shocked me.

in Microsoft Text Speech DLL there is something like this : SpVoice which is interface (they didn't put I as prefix for some reason and I don't know why ?) and SpVoiceClass. So then what's the problem you may ask, Here :

```
SpVoice speak= new SpVoice(); //I created an object from SpVoice Interface
speak.Speak("Hello StackOverFlow"); //and it speaks and say exactly what I write.
```

and

```
SpVoiceClass speak =  new SpVoiceClass();
speak.Speak("Hello Kowanichi"); //and it does the same thing.
```

The thing I don't get is how ? How does the first one work although it says it is an interface with tons of unimplemented methods etc.

Please some one explain me HOW ?

I am really confused now and maybe Microsoft developers didn't put I prefix for that reason, it can be instantiated.

Thanks in advance. 
Hope I describe my problem clearly.

**Here is the image that I want you to see :**
[image]
<sub>(source: [pixelshack.us](http://www.pixelshack.us/images/dngpe9kzoq83obtiami.png))</sub>

Comment: Is this C#? You can't instantiate interfaces then, no question about it.

Comment: Yeah I know but why  is it like that ?

Comment: Where did you get SpeechLib from?

Comment: Microsoft Speech Object Library from COM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**: Ah, I see.  Look at the definition of SpVoice:

```
[CoClass(typeof(SpVoiceClass))]
public interface SpVoice : ISpeechVoice, _ISpeechVoiceEvents_Event
{}
```

Then look up the CoClass attribute:

> A coclass supplies concrete
>   implementation(s) of one or more
>   interfaces. In COM, such concrete
>   implementations can be written in any
>   programming language that supports COM
>   component development, e.g. Delphi,
>   C++, Visual Basic, etc.

I'm not familiar with this, so don't take this as gospel, but it appears that, through compiler magic triggered by the `CoClass` attribute, you're instantiating an instance of `SpVoiceClass` when it looks like you're instantiating an interface.

Comment: I just imported Microsoft Speech Object Library into my project from COM.

Comment: and you can see the SpVoiceClass from the picture I put.

Comment: and would you tell me why I'd need a coclass ?

Comment: Do you mean, why does that attribute exist on that class when you could simply instantiate SpVoiceClass?  I don't know, but I'd guess convenience - maybe an old, primitive way to implement a Factory pattern.

Comment: Well according to what I've just read, it must be used when declaring COM Classes in your wrapper library.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do SpVoice speak= new SpVoice() and didn't get an error, then it means SpVoice has a constructor, which means that is is **NOT** an interface.

Comment: It's an interface. You can check it out yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: I edited my initial post and put a picture of it. Right below my question you can see the Hint when I bring the mouse over the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont take the "I" thing too far. Its just a naming convention.
Perhaps spVoice is not an interface. May  I know how you concluded spVoice is indeed an interface ?

If it is an interface it cant be instantiated.

Comment: I put the real and exact picture of it.