# Determine if a type is static

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, instantiation

Let's say I have a `Type` called `type`.

I want to determine if I can do this with my type (without actually doing this to each type):

If `type` is `System.Windows.Point` then I could do this:

```
Point point1 = new Point();
```

However if `type` is `System.Environment` then this will not fly:

```
Environment environment1 = new Environment(); //wrong
```

So if I am iterating through every visible type in an assembly how do I skip all the types that will fail to create an instance like the second one?  I'm kind of new to reflection so I'm not that great with the terminology yet.  Hopefully what I'm trying to do here is pretty clear.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`static` classes are declared `abstract` and `sealed` at the IL level. So, you can check `IsAbstract` property to handle both `abstract` classes and `static` classes in one go (for your use case).

However, `abstract` classes are not the only types you can't instantiate directly. You should check for things like interfaces ([without the `CoClass` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-compiler-detect-com-types)) and types that don't have a constructor accessible by the calling code.

Answer (score 27):

```
type.IsAbstract && type.IsSealed
```

This would be a sufficient check for C# since an abstract class cannot be sealed or static in C#.  However, you'll need to be careful when dealing with CLR types from other languages.

Answer (score 7):

you can search for public contructors like this,

```
Type t = typeof(Environment);
var c = t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);
if (!t.IsAbstract && c.Length > 0)
{
     //You can create instance
}
```

Or if you only interested in parameterless constructor you can use

```
Type t = typeof(Environment);
var c = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
if (c != null && c.IsPublic && !t.IsAbstract )
{
     //You can create instance
}
```

Comment: Note that an `abstract` class can have a `public` constructor. You can't necessarily create an instance of a class in the body of your `if` statement. You'll get `MemberAccessException`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Type t = typeof(System.GC);
Console.WriteLine(t.Attributes);
TypeAttributes attribForStaticClass = TypeAttributes.AutoLayout | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.Class |
TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit;
Console.WriteLine((t.Attributes == attribForStaticClass));
```

I guess, this should work.

Comment: I believe the only one unique to static classes is the `TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit` -- this is what I use to determine static classes. Checking `IsAbstract` and `IsSealed` also guarantees only static types but it's a more involved check.

Answer (score -4):

This is a way to get all public contstuctors of all types in an assembly.

```
    var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()[0]; // first assembly for demo purposes
var types = assembly.GetTypes();
foreach (var type in types)
{
    var constructors = type.GetConstructors();
}
```