# How to tell if a Type is a static class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine if a type is static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175888/determine-if-a-type-is-static)

**Duplicate of** [Determine if a type is static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175888/determine-if-a-type-is-static)

Is there a property/attribute I can inspect to see if a `System.Type` is a static class?

I can do this indirectly, by testing that the `Type` has static methods, and no instance methods beyond those inherited from `System.Object`, however it doesn't **feel** clean (I've a sneaking suspicion I'm missing something and this isn't a rigorous enough definition of `static class`).

Is there something I'm missing on the type that will categorically tell me **this is a static class**?

Or is `static class` c# syntax sugar and there's no way to express it in IL?

Thanks
BW

Comment: Determine if a type is static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175888/determine-if-a-type-is-static

Comment: It's mostly C# syntax. What do you need to detect it for?

Comment: @CD: How the hell did I miss that, I searched extensively before posting the question. Master, your search-fu is greater than mine :)

Comment: @Gabe: I want to automatically generate Interfaces and instance classes that map directly to static classes (e.g. File & Directory in System.IO.File, and MANY legacy static classes in our code base. I'm trying to introduce Unit testing and these are a major road block to using Mocks for tests. If I can I'll auto generate wrappers, far too much to do to hand-code them.

Comment: First time I've voted to close my own question *sigh*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

yea, you need to test for both `IsAbstract` and `IsSealed`. A non static class can never be both. Not fantastic but it works.

Answer (score 9):

At IL level any static class is abstract and sealed. So you can do something like this:

```
    Type myType = typeof(Form1);
    if (myType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null && myType.IsAbstract && myType.IsSealed)
    {
        // class is static
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        if (typeof(C).Attributes.HasFlag(System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Abstract) &&
             typeof(C).Attributes.HasFlag(System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Sealed) && 
            typeof(C).Attributes.HasFlag(System.Reflection.TypeAttributes.Class) )
            {
            }
```

but may be there is a class with this attributes but it's not static