# Determine if type is instantiable or usable

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types

In the following example, the comment is meant to check if a type is instantiable or usable:

```
class TypeContract
{
    Type indicator;

    public TypeContract(Type type)
    {
        // if (!type.IsInstantiable)
        // {
        //    throw new ArgumentException();
        // }

        indicator = type;
    }
}
```

For reference, `System.String` is instantiable, but `System.Convert`, `IDictionary<,>` and `TKey` are not. Note that constructor accessibility is not a concern in terms of classes.

How does the C# compiler check this? Is there a reliable type attribute? Perhabs it uses a manual check like:

`!((type.IsAbstract && type.IsSealed) || type.IsGenericParameter || type.ContainsGenericParameters)`

Comment: "For reference, `System.String` is instantiable, but `System.Convert`, `IDictionary<,>` and `TKey` are not." What *exactly* do you mean by this? What criteria are you trying to impose?

Comment: By "Is Instantiantiable" do you mean Value vs Reference type?  Or do you mean "has a public constructor I can use?"  Or maybe even both?

Comment: I stuggle to find known terminology, what I practically mean is: What types can be referred to in code, without `typeof` .

Comment: Note that your mention of `TKey` is incorrect. Since you're checking the metadata via `Type` at runtime, `TKey` may be instantiable depending on the `Type` passed in for it.

Comment: @Avavol - `TKey` is descriptive, so certainly not usable.

Comment: What about classes that have private constructors that are exposed via public static methods?

Comment: Seems to me you're mixing things up here. `IDictionary` is an interface; you can't create an instance of an interface, though you can instantiate a type that implements the interface. `System.Convert` is a static class; you can't create an instance of a static class. TKey is typically the type parameter for a generic class or method; it's like the argument to a function. The rules for each would be different.

Comment: Actually you may access EVERY type (includinbg interfaces which are not instantiable) via `typeof`.

Comment: @DavidG - Constructor accessibility is not a concern.

Comment: The compiler does not need to check for those weird attributes, it simply checks if the class is actually an interface or abstract or even static, that´s it.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense really. You can create a class with only private constructors which renders it "uninstantiatable".

Comment: @DavidG - Thats fine because I'm not interested in implementation details, I need to know whether a type is instantiable (at all) and referable as an object or structure, even if that involves an interface. I know that `Type` has plenty of properties which lend a good start, but I need a clean approach.

Answer (score 4):

[`Type.GetConstructors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the public constructors of a class.

You can check if it returns an empty list

Answer (score 2):

Get the `Type` object for the class and check the following attributes:

Class is static:  `type.IsAbstract && type.IsSealed` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175888/determine-if-a-type-is-static))

Class is an interface: `type.IsInterface`

Class is an enum: `type.IsEnum`

Class is a generic parameter:  `type.IsGenericParameter`

Check the documentation for the Type class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info on the properties it provides.

After that, you can check the available constructors.