# Exposing the Connection token from Connect-AzureAd

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the [AzureAd Powershell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.0.55) for user management. However it does not have all the functionality that I need, specifically, I can't assign Application Extension values to objects, (although I can create delete and remove application extensions themselves via `[Get/New/Remove]-AzureADApplicationExtensionProperty`).

I know from watching the API calls with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) that the graph calls are using bearer tokens, and I've called the graph API directly from Postman manually so I know how to use the Bearer token if I could get it. How do I get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the token simply use:

> $token = [Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AzureSession]::AccessTokens['AccessToken']

But how could one come to this conclusion?

First look for where the module is located:

```
(Get-Module AzureAd).Path
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureAD\2.0.1.3\Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Graph.PowerShell.dll
```

Now lets just make 2 assumptions. First that the token is stored in a static member of a static class, and second that it might not be stored in that dll, but any of the DLLs in the folder.

```
$fileInfo = New-Object 'IO.FileInfo' (Get-Module AzureAd).Path
$moduleFolder = $fileInfo.Directory.FullName
$assemblies = [AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | where { $_.Location -ne $null -and  $_.Location.StartsWith($moduleFolder)}
$assemblies | select -expandproperty ExportedTypes | Where { $_.IsSealed -and $_.IsAbstract } | Select Name, FullName
```

That last line btw is because of the weird way [static types are noted in IL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175888/determine-if-a-type-is-static).

Which outputs a very small list:

```
Name                                          FullName
----                                          --------
RestSharpExtensionMethods                     Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.RestSharpExtensionMethods
AzureSession                                  Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AzureSession
DictionaryExtensions                          Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.DictionaryExtensions
Logger                                        Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.Logger
ImageUtils                                    Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.Utilities.ImageUtils
SecureStringExtension                         Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.Extensions.SecureStringExtension
AzureEnvironmentConstants                     Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AzureEnvironment+AzureEnvironmentConstants
TypeToOdataTypeMapping                        Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.TypeToOdataTypeMapping
JsonConvert                                   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
Extensions                                    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.Extensions
Extensions                                    Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Extensions
TypeToOdataTypeMapping                        Microsoft.Open.MSGraphV10.Client.TypeToOdataTypeMapping
AdalError                                     Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalError
AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContextIntegratedAuthExtensions
AdalOption                                    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalOption
MiscExtensions                                RestSharp.Extensions.MiscExtensions
ReflectionExtensions                          RestSharp.Extensions.ReflectionExtensions
ResponseExtensions                            RestSharp.Extensions.ResponseExtensions
ResponseStatusExtensions                      RestSharp.Extensions.ResponseStatusExtensions
StringExtensions                              RestSharp.Extensions.StringExtensions
XmlExtensions                                 RestSharp.Extensions.XmlExtensions
RestClientExtensions                          RestSharp.RestClientExtensions
SimpleJson                                    RestSharp.SimpleJson
```

We could pipe through [Out-Gridview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-5.1) if the list was longer, but my attention was immediatly drawn to `AzureSession`. After that a little PowerShell autocomplete, and I found my way to `[Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AzureSession]::AccessTokens['AccessToken']`