# Resolving an Interop Dependency across projects

Tags: interop, ninject, excel-interop

Another telegraph-style question. First, my NinjectModule:

```
using Ninject.Modules;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace NinjectSample.Util.Injection
{
    public class SampleModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<_Application>().ToMethod(ctx => GetApp());
        }

        public _Application GetApp()
        {
            return new Application();
        }
    }
}
```

First thing (works!):

```
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SampleModule());
        var foo = kernel.Get<_Application>();
```

Changing this to

```
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SampleModule());
        var foo = kernel.Get<BusinessClass>();
```

`BusinessClass` is defined in another Assembly, Code:

```
namespace BusinessClassLibrary
{
    public class BusinessClass
    {
        private _Application _app;

        [Inject]
        public BusinessClass(_Application application)
        {
            _app = application;
        }
    }
}
```

This will Result in :

```
Error activating _Application
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency _Application into parameter application of constructor of type BusinessClass
  1) Request for BusinessClass

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for _Application.
  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
  4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
  5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

I'm not too deep into interop, but my basic understanding of .Net lets me stumble across the following:

- `Application` is an interface, just like its base `_Application`. Nevertheless it is possible to call its constructor. Why?
- I tell Ninject to use a factory Method, which seems to work while the dependency is located in the Assembly that the Kernel is defined in. Why does it try to resolve the Dependency by self-binding when it's located in another assembly?

Answer (score 1):

> Application is an interface, just like its base _Application.
>   Nevertheless it is possible to call its constructor. Why?

This is a compiler trick; see [Creating instance of interface in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482508/creating-instance-of-interface-in-c-sharp) for information on what is happening. It definitely looks strange when you encounter it in the code. Unfortunately, can't help you with the actual Ninject part of the question at the moment.