# Is it possible to compile a C# method that has non-void return type, but does not return a value?

Tags: c#, syntax, dsl

Is it possible to somehow compile `X M() { /*...*/ }` given the following constraints:

1. You can't add any other modifiers to `M`.
2. `/*...*/` does not contain `return` or `throw`, and you can't change it.
3. You can't add rewriters to the compiler pipeline.
4. You can change everything else around `M`.

It might seem like a nonsensical question, but it is actually valuable for DSLs.
E.g. I could define something like `task M() {}` which would just denote that it is a task, and have nothing to do with a return value.

Comment: If it returns Task and have modifier `async`, you don't need to return anything. Is it acceptable?

Comment: @CodeCaster: "abstract method" would fail constraint #1 though.

Comment: Is that [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)? :D

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789832/missing-return-statement-in-a-non-void-method-compiles

Comment: so no `async Task foo()` I take it?

Comment: @Kilazur: No... code golf is about writing the shortest program possible. This has nothing to do with code length.

Comment: @BoltClock meh, the joke was "does it belong to code golf stack exchange", you big meanie

Comment: Note that 'it is not possible' is a valid answer (I wish `using X = System.Void` worked...).

Comment: In C#, denoting things is done via attributes, not return types. `[task] void M() { ... }`. It sounds like you are trying to make your DSL follow C# syntax rules, which creates a conflict when your DSL and C# disagree. Trying to change the syntax of C# is not the correct solution to the problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right on the situation. But I think it is always useful to know my options. Yes, I can always choose a better solution later on. But I still found the question interesting, since it is often possible to find surprises in C# (esp. in unsafe or COM parts), e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482508/creating-instance-of-interface-in-c-sharp etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a method:

```
public Foo Bar()
{
    DoX();

    DoY();

    DoZ();
}
```

Which doesn't compile, because the only path in the method doesn't return anything.

Given your constraints (basically: you have to compile the code as-is, with a standard C# compiler), the answer is: no, you can't make this compile.

Comment: It is basically a DSL. So you want to let your user write `task X() { doA(); doB(); doC(); }` without bothering with returns. I haven't considered `while`, but it has the same problem — it is unnatural for a DSL user to add it.

Comment: Then why bother the user with a return type?

Comment: Because logically it is not a return type — it is a marker that it is a task. Is there a shorter way in C# to describe it? A workable alternative I am considering is `task X = () => {...}`.

Comment: How does the code your users type get incorporated in the code you want to compile? Can't you put that code in an `void Execute()` method of your `Task` class?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin It seems pretty clear here that you have an XY problem.  Explain what you're *actually* trying to accomplish, and people can propose ways for you to design your program such that it will accomplish your *real* goals in the best possible manor.

Comment: @Servy I do not believe that underlying problem is fit for StackOverflow — "what's the shortest syntax for a given C# DSL" is subjective and would probably be closed. However the question whether I can do a specific thing in C# is a yes/no question that is not subjective. Note that "no" is a valid answer here — I noticed SO is often reluctant to give it for some reason.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin The answer to your question *isn't* no.  This answer answers the question you asked.  Of course, it looks like it doesn't help you in the least in solving your real problem, because we have no idea what your real problem is and you didn't ask about it.  Without knowing anything about what you're actually trying to do I couldn't tell you how to ask it appropriately on SO, but clearly this isn't getting you anywhere.

Comment: @Andrey like this, see edit? The problem with "no" usually is that the answer is "No, but that most likely isn't the answer you want to hear".

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually that's an absolutely valid answer, thank you. I did reduce my problem to yes/no question exactly because I see a value in yes/no answer. I'll consider how I can ask the larger question within current SO rules, but that would be a separate question anyway (if I even can ask it).

Answer (score 2):

Adding in some additional information from the `C#` specification.

This first paragraph states that a method must have a return type, or void.

> Methods have a (possibly empty) list of parameters, which represent values or variable references passed to the method, and a return type, which specifies the type of the value computed and returned by the method. A method’s return type is void if it does not return a value.

This second paragraph specifies that a method with a non-void return type must have a calculable return expression.

> A method can use return statements to return control to its caller. In a method returning void, return statements cannot specify an expression. In a method returning non-void, return statements must include an expression that computes the return value.

Even though the specification does not explicitly state that method must contain a return statement, I believe it implicitly says so.

So no, it is not possible according to the `C#` specification.

Answer (score 0):

maybe,

```
abstract class Whatever
{
    public abstract X M<X>();
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work without compiler rewriting and does not allow a body at all. Same with `partial` btw.