# Why is it possible to create a new instance of a COM interface?

Tags: c#, com, interop, coclass

I don't have very much background regarding COM nor coclasses, so I don't quite understand why I can use the `new` operator with an interface. From a language/framework-agnostic view, it's confusing why this compiles and runs correctly:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class ExcelProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application excel = new Application();
    }
}
```

Inspecting `Application` in Visual Studio 2010 shows me:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the entire Microsoft Excel application.
    [Guid("000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [CoClass(typeof(ApplicationClass))]
    public interface Application : _Application, AppEvents_Event
    {
    }
}
```

What is going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is only possible for COM interfaces, I believe. Marc Gravell has an explanation [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/08/who-says-you-cant-instantiate-interface.html).

The short answer is that a COM interface can be paired with a "default" implementation class, so that when you "instantiate" the interface you're actually creating an instance of that default implementation class. In the case of the `Application` interface in your example, that appears to be `ApplicationClass`.

Comment: Thanks. That link had a link to a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-compiler-detect-com-types. Guess I was searching for the wrong keywords - looks like my question is essentially a duplicate.