# What does the C# CoClass attribute do?

Tags: c#, coclass

I found code something like the following in a 3rd party library we're using.

```
[CoClass(typeof(BlahClass))]
public interface Blah : IBlah
{
}
```

What is this doing exactly?  The msdn documentation didn't illuminate the subject sufficiently for me to follow.

Comment: `CoClass` is a COM concept. If you don't understand COM, then you won't understand `CoClass`.

Comment: The discussion on this question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-compiler-detect-com-types

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the C# compiler detect COM types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-detect-com-types)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It declares that the interface `Blah` is intended to be implemented by a specific class. It means that you can conveniently say `new Blah` and the runtime will know what object to create - something that is not normally possible with an interface.

If you look at the generated declaration for BlahClass, it will presumably have a `Guid` associated with it which can be used to create an instance of a COM object.

Comment: OK, that makes sense in light of what I'm seeing in the surrounding code.  Thanks!  Besides the COM thing, is there any advantage to this method vs. just implementing the interface?

Comment: I need the answer of your comment @RobertGowland. Is it nessecary to implement this class or declaring the interface would be enough?

Comment: @MohammadGoudarzi The attribute `[CoClass(typeof(BlahClass))]` mentions the class `BlahClass`, so that class must exist somewhere. And it must implement the interface `Blah`. In an interop assembly generated from a COM type library, `BlahClass` will really be a COM object (possibly implemented in C++, VB6, Delphi or something else entirely...)