# Why does C# allow constructing an object from an interface in "new Shell32.Shell()"?

Tags: c#, interface, shell32.dll

I know that in C# in general you can't create an instance of an abstract class or an interface. Can someone help me understand this code (it compile without any errors).

```
Shell32.Shell shObj = new Shell32.Shell();
```

`Shell32.Shell` is an interface from 'shell32.dll'

I tried the following, but it did NOT compile:

```
[CoClass(typeof(ShellClass))]
[Guid("286E6F1B-7113-4355-9562-96B7E9D64C54")]
public interface OtherShell : Shell
{
}
OtherShell shObj = new OtherShell();
```

---

Update:

To make it work, I just needed to add the `ComImport` attribute and change the co-class (I can't choose Shell32.ShellClass).

Thanks guys!

Comment: It's a COM object. An Interop Assembly is generated when the COM DLL is imported into the project. There is some other magic therein - the actual class is 'Shell32.ShellClass'. Using Code Navigation on the "new Shell" code moves to the ShellClass implementation, not the Shell interface, so there is further magic..

Comment: What makes you think it is an interface?

Comment: @BuhBuh Viewing the interop assembly: "[Guid("286E6F1B-7113-4355-9562-96B7E9D64C54")] [CoClass(typeof (ShellClass))] [ComImport] public *interface* Shell .." (ShellClass extends Shell).

Comment: Short answer: You are correct that interfaces cannot be instantiated. What you've stumbled upon is some piece of obscure syntactic sugar that facilitates instantiation of COM classes.

Comment: No need to mark questions solved - the answers do that. You can always answer your own questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to all the other information, here is the *how* it results in compiled code. The usage of the interface is merely a code nicety.

```
IL_000c: newobj       instance void [Interop.Shell32]Shell32.ShellClass::.ctor()
```

That is, it is a *compile-time* transformation from the interface "to" the class, based on the [CoClass] attribute.

Per, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094140/2864740, which shows a minimal example case:

> [In addition to CoClassAttribute, you] *need both the ComImportAttribute and the GuidAttribute for it to work*.

Comment: Which is pretty much against C#'s own language standard, which states you can't instantiate interfaces...

Comment: @Adrian It's a "magical compiler transform", unicorns and talking cats D:

Comment: I get that, It just would be nice if it was actually something that's specified.

Comment: @Adrian I would also like better .. documentation on such behavior :}

Answer (score 1):

If you right click in Visual Studio on Shell32.Shell and go to definition you'll get the following definition of the interface:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Shell32
{
    [CoClass(typeof(ShellClass))]
    [Guid("286E6F1B-7113-4355-9562-96B7E9D64C54")]
    public interface Shell : IShellDispatch6
    {
    }
}
```

Do the same on the ShellClass and you'll get the concrete class that's being created in your code:

```
Shell32.Shell shObj = new Shell32.Shell();
```

Comment: I wonder what is responsible for "creating" the object (for the right impl.) to honor the CoClass attribute..? That is, how does C#/specify know that this interface is special, or is the attribute itself sufficient (at what 'level' does the magic occur)? Is there special MSIL generated (and/or how does it differ from a normal ctor call); that is, is it run-time or compile-time magic to select the ShellClass? Where might this be documented?

Comment: CoClassAttribute is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960910/what-does-the-c-sharp-coclass-attribute-do

Comment: That also only gives a high-level explanation, but not the details :( If we've decided that .NET *can't* instantiate interfaces, then there has to be some 'special mechanism' by which the looks-like-interface-instantiation is "converted" to the actual object creation.

Comment: @Adrian Answers there still say 'what to make it work', without saying *how* it works.. :}

Comment: Get hold of the source code (it's all available) and dig through https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/attributes.cs,7288373bd0dc8648