# COM interface instantiation C#

Tags: c#, com, interface, instantiation

I am working with the CDO COM DLL for handling `.eml` files. When I try to instantiate the MessengerClass class, VC#2010 tells me I have to instantiate using the interface e.g.

```
CDO.Message msg = new CDO.Message();
```

instead of

```
CDO.Message msg = new CDO.MessageClass();
```

How can this be? Wont all the functionality be missing from this instance?
[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx) says to do the same thing. 
What am I missing? Does an interface still contain usable functionality?

Comment: This is COM.  Normal rules do not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler translates `new COMInterface()` into actual COM code that looks up the COM class that implements the interface.

As I understand, COM interfaces do not have multiple implementations; instead, the runtime loads the implementation from appropriate DLL specified in HKCR\Classes{*guid*}.
(I don't know much about COM, so this may be inaccurate.

Comment: This does explain some things.

Answer (score 1):

The CDO.Message class exposes the IMessage, IBodyPart and IDataSource interfaces according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526599%28v=exchg.10%29)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-detect-com-types) has more details on some of the C#/COM behind the scenes magic.

Comment: when viewing the Message interface definition in VC#2010 it contains [CoClass(typeof(MessageClass))], and MessengerClass is defined as a bunch of virtual functions. I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the CDO reference
right click on it
chose Properties
and change the property of Embed Interop Types to False