# Difference between Inspector and InspectorClass

Tags: com, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, coclass

I've been looking at the VSTO libraries, mostly for the fun of it, and I noticed that there's something called `Inspector` as well as `InspectorClass`.

What's the difference, why is it there and how can I put it to use? *(NB I'm not looking for an answer on **how** to code using those classes but rather what the rationale behind that certain architecture pattern is. Purely academical curiosity.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`InspectorClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorclass.aspx) is a [coclass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model#Classes) (*concrete implementation*) of the [`Inspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspector.aspx) COM interface (*e.g. it is a COM object with metadata + code*). An `Inspector` can be instantiated directly even though it exists purely as an interface definition ([*it actually instantiates `InspectorClass`behind the scenes*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093623/175679)).

`InspectorClass` can be instantiated since it represents a concrete class instance, although as [VSTO added support for embedding interop types in .NET 4](http://badecho.com/2010/08/office-and-embedded-interop-types/) - [support for the `*Class` usage is no longer used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553402/175679) and serves to exist more or less for [backwards compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa155703%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_oladdinvbnet_topic2).

All this to say is that you should now be using `Inspector` and not `InspectorClass` which can contain executable code. From [MSDN blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2009/12/07/interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead.aspx):

> *...it is safe to embed metadata but not anything that can potentially contain executable code (**class types contain metadata AND code while interfaces only contain metadata**)*

From this statement, you can deduce that `InspectorClass` contains executable code, while `Inspector` does not - it is purely an interface (*metadata*). This means that embedding interop types does not allow support for the `*Class` implementations.