# Calling Method of subclass over interface without implementing the method there

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have the interface `IPet` and in another project I have the class `Dog` which inherits from `IPet`.
In `Dog` I have the method `Bark()` but not in `IPet`.
In the project of `IPet` I have also the class `PetSimulation` in which I have an instance of `IPet`.
Now I want to make something like this:

```
IPet myDog = new IPet("Rex");  
myDog.Bark();
```

But `IPet` does not have the method `Bark()` and that should remain that way because other classes such as `Cat` and `Horse` are also inherit from `IPet` but don't have the method `Bark` either.
Also I can't do something like this:

```
Dog myDog = new Dog("Rex");
```

because `Dog` is in another project.

Is there any way for me to call the Method `Bark` of the subclass `Dog` over the interface `IPet` without implementing the method there?

Comment: Can you add a new method `Speak()` to your interface?

Comment: @DanPichelman No, the interface has to remain, as it is right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. But you could make an interface IDog with the method Bark, that would inherit from IPet

```
public interface IPet
{

}

public interface IDog : IPet
{
    void Bark();    
}

public class Dog : IDog
{
    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wouff!");    
    }
}
```

Comment: So this would lead to you beeing able to call the method Bark. But you still can't create an IDog object in a projects / assembly without having a reference to a project / assembly that contains an actual implementation -- a class that *derives* from IDog. The interface has no "code body" it is a contract and it just defines what behavior is available, not how it is performed.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer:

You can test the `IPet` to see if it is a `Dog`, like this:

```
Dog dog = myDog as Dog;
if (dog != null)
{
    dog.Bark();
}
```

Note that you can't directly create an interface like you do in the question, except in [very rare circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093623/1595658).

Comment: I see... That does not work for me because at that point i do not have access to Dog, only to IPet.  With the implemetation: The original code is much longer and more complicated. I wanted to make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast myDog to Dog in order to access methods that only that class has:

```
IPet myDog = new IPet("Rex");  
((Dog)myDog).Bark();
```

If you implement Bark in the interface then it will be required for all classes that implement it.

Can you access Dog by adding a reference to Dog's project?

Comment: No because the Project of _Dog_ is the main project and already has an reference to the project of _IPet_. So i cant add a reference the other way round...

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot access the Dog class and are working in .NET 4+ you could try

```
dynamic dog = new ...
dog.Bark()
```