# Why can I do a new on an interface of an Interop Assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

consider the following code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

If I look at the interop assembly with the object explorer I see that `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` is defined as:

```
public interface Application
    Member of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
```

Then why can I do a new on it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-sharp-compiler-detect-com-types